# find first different node or edge

Tags: python, networkx

I have 2 directed graphs (`networkx.DiGraph`)

I want to find first Node or Edge which is different

- Please take into account Edge.label when comparing Edges

What is the NetworkX's way to find first inequivalent item

Comment: What do you mean by first Node? In graph theory Nodes is a set, and so do Edges.

Comment: @DaniMesejo my graph represent a traceroute of a packet (packet can can to more than one "Node"), both graphs are mostly the same, I can traverse breadth first and compare but I guess there is a better NetworkX interface for that, am I wrong ?